# Proving that $e(X,Y)\ge k$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

**Question:**

Let $G$ be a graph with chromatic number larger than $k$, whose vertex set is partioned into sets $X$ and $Y$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have the same chromatic number $k$. Prove that there is at least $k$ edges between $X$ and $Y$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose $e(X,Y)\le k-1$

Since $\chi (\langle X\rangle)=\chi (\langle Y\rangle)=k$ so let $X=S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_k$ and $Y=S'_1 \cup \cdots \cup S'_k$where $S_1, \cdots, S_k, S'_1, \cdots, S'_k$ are stables partioning $X$ and $Y$.

Define a bipartite graph $H=H(X',Y')$ with $X'=s_1, \cdots, s_k$ and $Y'=s'_1, \cdots, s'_k$ such that $s_is'_j \in E(H)$ iff no vertex in $S_i$ is adjacent to a vertex in $S'_j$ (i.e. $S_i$ and $S'_j$ are stable). Also since $e(X,Y)\le k-1$ then $d(v) \ge 1$  $\forall v \in H$.

It is enough to prove that $H$ has a perfect matching.

Suppose that $H$ doesn't have a perfect matching then according to Hall-Rado's theorem, there exist a set $S \subset X$ such that $|S|>|N(S)|$

And I am struggling to find a contradiction. Actually I was trying to prove this statement, (there exist $s_i,s_j \in S$ such that they both have a unique neighbor $s'_a$) but I am not able to do it.

Can anyone help me complete my method please? Or if not maybe just give another way to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S \subset X'$, there are no edges (in $H$) between $S$ and $Y' - N(S)$. What do these missing edges in $H$ tell you about the original graph $G$, especially in the case where $|N(S)| < |S|$?

Comment: It means that the sets of $S$ (in G) are connected with the sets of $Y-N(S)$, and then we can conclude that $e(X,Y)>|S|$ then by taking $S=X$ we'll get that $e(X,Y)>k$. Right?

Comment: @FareedAF if there's no perfect matching, Hall's theorem tells you there is *some* $S \subset X'$ with $|N(S)| < |S|$, but you aren't necessarily able to take $S = X'$.

Comment: True, then how can we assure that $e(X,Y)>k-1$ to reach a contradiction?

Comment: Well, look at the other extreme -- what if there were a single-vertex set $S \subset X'$ with $|N(S)| < |S|$. Could you get the conclusion you needed then? Could you push the technique to deal with other sizes?

Comment: Yes I think so, if $|S|=1$ then $|N(S)|=0$ which means that in $H$ this vertex is not connected to any other vertex in $Y'$ so, there is a set $S_i$ that is connected to all the other sets in $G$ so $e(X,Y)>k-1$

Comment: But can you please help me in a way to write it if $|S|=s$ for example ? I thought about it for $|S|=3$ and I got to the contradiction but I am still not finding a neat way to write it in. So please if you can write it down. I think maybe we must take two cases if $s>\frac{k}{2}$ and if $s \le \frac{k}{2}$ ?

Comment: If $|S| = s$ and $|N(S)| < S$, then what can you say about $|Y - N(S)|$?

(I don't think splitting into those two cases is necessarily useful here.)

Comment: $$|Y-N(S)|>k-s$$ Also I think we must have that $k\ge s$ to complete the proof? I wasn't able to prove that either. We'll know that $e(X,Y)>s(k-s)$ right?

Comment: can you please write the full solution?

Comment: Yes, the inequality $e(X,Y) > s(k-s)$ is essentially what you need here. (In fact, you can get the stronger statement $e(X,Y) \geq s(k-s+1)$ by using $|Y - N(S)| > k-s$ and the fact that both quantities are integers.) You need $k \geq s$ but this should not be difficult to prove if you think about what $k$ and $s$ mean. You have all the ingredients you need; I'm not going to write out a full solution for you.